# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics Causing frequent 499 errors in Application Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights, .net-8.0

We recently rebuilt our central API from a 4.8 project to a Net8. Both services are running side by side using deployment slots with a 50/50 split of traffic either hitting the original route, or the new Net8 build. (To clarify, decided not to use MS Migration tool, just rebuilt from a file/new net 8 project).

In the last several days, Application Insights has shown a high number of failures to the base url of the API.

[image: High app insights failures against Get/]

We initially assumed there was an issue with the KeepAlive on the app service, but from going through the logs and documentation, the frequency of these requests is too high for Keep Alive, when I watch the Application log stream that particular event is easily identifiable and returns a 200.

Eventually we identified that the source of request is from the app service's own local host, and further investigation revealed this event in the log stream:

```
2024-02-09 11:02:56.635 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET [BASE URL OF THE API]/ - 499 - - 0.7112ms
```

This *seems* to be NET8 related, and the only thing I could see from looking online is this github ticket, relating to middleware, but we are not using the same middleware/not using UseExceptionHandler or UseTimeout. This is the ticket I refer to: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52295

Is anyone able to give any recommendations, or experiences to how we can stop these calls or at least configure the service to handle them more appropriately?

We did think it could be because there is nothing at /, but now we return an empty page, which works fine with Keep Alive. In case it is relevant, we are not using minimal API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @JimDev, the main root cause of the HTTP 499 errors in the application is not entirely clear. However, I have provided you with a set of reproducible answer and suggestions you can check with that and comeback with the requirements.

Comment: All sorted, turns out it was a rogue SignalR in an application that was attempting to hit our API.

Answer (score 1):

> To clarify, decided not to use MS Migration tool, just rebuilt from a file/new net 8 project.

Here I have created a new ASP.NET Core project targeting .NET 8 to test and also configured base URL in the application by following this [link](https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-get-base-url-in-asp-net-core/)

**program.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WebApplication15
{
    public static class HttpRequestExtensions
    {
        public static string? BaseUrl(this HttpRequest req)
        {
            if (req == null) return null;
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(req.Scheme, req.Host.Host, req.Host.Port ?? -1);
            if (uriBuilder.Uri.IsDefaultPort)
            {
                uriBuilder.Port = -1;
            }

            return uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); // Add HttpContextAccessor

            var app = builder.Build();

            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

- I also configured deployment slots to enable traffic splitting between the old and new versions of your API by this traffic generates to my API by making requests to the endpoints.
- For 499 errors make some adjustments in timeout settings, modifying middleware configurations, optimizing request handling logic, or making changes to the deployment setup.

I have no failure issues with my application I got only the invalid operation exception that too at beginning.

[image]